In IMAP , if i use imap.move with valid uids i get "this socket has been ended by the other party" error in imap.once("error")
firstly i try get imap by ,
let imap = new Imap({
  user: username,
  password: appPassword,
  host: host,
  //authentication: appPassword,
  port: 993,
  autotls: "always",
  tls: true,
  ssl: true,
  tlsOptions: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    servername: host
  },
  connTimeout: 30000,
  authTimeout: 30000,
});

then i pass the imap and connect using
imap.connect();
imap.once("ready", () => {
  resolve(imap);
});
imap.once("error", async(error) => {
  if (error.message.toLowerCase() === "this socket has been ended by the other party") {
    imap.end();
  }
});

the connection is made successfully,
after this i get the valid uids to delete , valid trash label.
then i open the correct mailbox to move from , then i use
imap.move(uids, trashFolderName, async function(err) {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
    return;
  }
}

here the problem starts - the uids get moved to trash but i get error "this socket has been ended by the other party" and the code after imap.move doesnot gets executed.
i dont know how to solve it.
if you already experienced in this , kindly help.

The imaplib tag is for a Python library. What NPM library are you using?

If it's this I don't see a resolve() method. And the example shows all the work being done inside the imap.once("ready") callback.

Are you running multiple commands in parallel?
